# Replace Nmap with Nessus

Tags: nmap, ports, network-scanners, nessus, host-discovery

I have to replace NMAP with Nessus. I got answer for few settings, but there are few settings in NMAP for which I am not able to get answer. If you could answer me, it would be helpful.

For example,

1. **NMAP Option "-Pn"** - Use: Do not use host discovery. Port scan w/o responding to ping

*Equivalent Nessus Option:* "Use Fast Network Discovery"

**These are other options for which I could not find the answer:**

2. **NMAP Option "-r"** - Use: Do not randomize the order of ports

*Equivalent Nessus Option: ?*

3. **NMAP Option "-n"** - Use: Do not reverse DNS

*Equivalent Nessus Option: ?*

4. **NMAP Option "--max_rtt_timeout"** - Use: Time waiting for reply (Longest)

*Equivalent Nessus Option: ?*

5. **NMAP Option "--initial_rtt_timeout"** - Use: Time waiting for reply (initial value)

*Equivalent Nessus Option: ?*

Comment: This is essentially a documentation question, and varies to some extent depending on the version of Nessus you're using. For example, in Nessus 7, the option "Scan IP addresses in a random order" is effectively "-r", but in some versions, it's called "Avoid sequential scan". The link you want is probably:  https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/AdvancedSettings.htm#AdvGeneralSettings

Comment: @Matthew Thank you for information. I have gone through the document link. The one you mentioned talks about IP and not the port. Do you think it will work in the same order? I do not find answers for other options too.

Comment: That's true - sorry, was skim reading and misread. It's hard to tell what order Nessus scans ports in, and I wouldn't want to rely on it being randomised from that setting.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to remember:

- nessus is not a discovery tool
- is not made to be fast

BTW have a flexible networking scanner.
When you create the policy for the scan. Take a look at discovery tab and port scanning.
Can do also tcp and udp ping.
By default scan the ports in from first to the last. But there is also the random option. Play a bit with the home edition